# Can we access Microsoft SQL Server database on WAN?

Tags: sql-server

I just want to ask that can we access Microsoft SQL Server database on WAN like My SQL Database? If so, then kindly guide me how?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q: Can you access MSSQL across a WAN?

A: Short answer: Yes.

In theory, you can access MSSQL anywhere across the network, including across a WAN network.

All you need are:

1. a route between your client and the MSSQL server, and
2. the MSSQL port (typically TCP port 1433) to be open.

If you can "ping" from your client to the remote host, you've got 1) covered.

In order to "open the port", however, you must:

a. Configure the MSSQL Server to use TCP/IP (this is *not* necessarily enabled by default)

b. Open port 1433 on the MSSQL Server's host

c. Configure the router(s) between your client and the host to open port 1433, and route requests on that port to your MSSQL Server's host

d. Configure any firewalls (including your client PC) to allow port 1433

Here is a link for opening your Windows firewall:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

Here is a link for configuring your router(s):

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483%28v=sql.105%29.aspx